# Getting Certificates from Java Keystore

Tags: java, linux, ssl-certificate, csr, crt

I am using Java Keystore to generate `domain.csr`, `domain.keystore` and `domain.cer`. I need to secure the domain using SSL for which I need `domain.crt` and `domain.key`. How can I get these two? Is there any difference between `domain.csr` and `domain.crt` or both are same? What is difference among all extensions like `csr`, `pem`, `crt`, `csr`etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to secure the domain using SSL for which I need domain.crt and domain.key. How can I get these two?

When you generate a self signed certificate, you usually obtain a private key (.key) and a certificate (.crt)

How have you generated your `domain.*` files? May be  `domain.keystore` is the key file you are looking for. Check the content of the file and see if the string `----- BEGIN PRIVATE KEY -----` is present

> Is there any difference between domain.csr and domain.crt or both are same?

They are different. `.csr` is the certificate signing request, and `.crt` is the certificate signed by the Certification Authority

> What is difference among all extensions like csr, pem, crt, csr etc.

From [here](https://support.ssl.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/19/0/der-vs-crt-vs-cer-vs-pem-certificates-and-how-to-convert-them)

- **.DER** = The DER extension is used for binary DER encoded certificates. These files may also bear the CER or the CRT extension.
- **.PEM** = The PEM extension is used for different types of X.509v3 files which contain ASCII (Base64) armored data prefixed with a “—– BEGIN …” line.
  Common Extensions
- **.CRT** = The CRT extension is used for certificates. The certificates may be encoded as binary DER or as ASCII PEM. The CER and CRT extensions are nearly synonymous.
- **.CER** = alternate form of .crt (Microsoft Convention)
- **.KEY** = The KEY extension is used both for public and private PKCS#8 keys. The keys may be encoded as binary DER or as ASCII PEM.
- **.CSR** = Certificate Signing Request encoded as binary DER or as ASCII PEM. Is used to contain a certificate request to a certificate authority